# On browser reload the angular app is redirected to previous component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In my Angular application I have 2 routes as below.

```
1. http://localhost:4200/lectures 
2. http://localhost:4200/lectures/{id}
```

The first route displays a list of lectures and the second route show a single lecture component. When I try to perform a browser reload on the second route it redirects to the first route or maybe a root route because I only have 2 routes and the root/empty route defaults to the first one. These routes/components don't have parent/child relationship and are independent of each other.

> Both the routes have some resolvers to fetch required data from service before the component gets rendered.
>
> How do I stop the application from redirecting to its previous component or I guess its a root component on a browser reload?
>
> I am also not able to go to the second route directly.
>
> I am using 'microsoft-adal-angular6' AuthenticationGuard on both the routes.

I have read this blog and tried already but it didn't work.
https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LectureDetailsComponent } from './lecture-details/lecture-details.component';
import { LectureListComponent } from './lecture-list/lecture-list.component';
import { LectureDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/lecture-detail.resolver';
import { LectureListResolver } from './_resolvers/lecture-list.resolver';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from 'microsoft-adal-angular6';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/lectures', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: 'lectures', component: LectureListComponent, resolve: { lectures: LectureListResolver }, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
  { path: 'lectures/:id', component: LectureDetailsComponent, resolve: { lecture: LectureDetailResolver }, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthenticationGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  
}
```

the expectation is that the page refreshes on the same route/component but the actual result is the application gets redirected to the previous/root component

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to reorder your routes so that the empty route comes after your two component routes, from the docs (https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration):

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

And you should add a wildcard at the end as well, so your route config would look more like this(wildcard route doesn't need `pathMatch`).

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'lectures',
    component: LectureListComponent,
    resolve: { lectures: LectureListResolver },
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'lectures/:id',
    component: LectureDetailsComponent,
    resolve: { lecture: LectureDetailResolver },
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/lectures',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/lectures',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  }
];
```

And now the empty route is redundant, so you can remove it.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'lectures',
    component: LectureListComponent,
    resolve: { lectures: LectureListResolver },
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'lectures/:id',
    component: LectureDetailsComponent,
    resolve: { lecture: LectureDetailResolver },
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/lectures',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  }
];
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I have made the required changes as per your suggestions but it still doesn't work. Also when I try to access the second route directly it redirects back to the first one.

Comment: Can you confirm that the session passes the AuthenticationGuard? Because your empty route is redirecting to /lectures which has the guard and if fails might redirect back to the empty route again, might be better to have another component for the empty route to avoid that circular routing

Comment: I have removed the empty route so not it shouldn't be a circular routing. I do see token printed in the console when reloaded

Comment: @kuroneko0441 thanks for the reply and I have removed the blank route now it still wont resolve it.

Comment: also guys coming back one of my questions is why I am not able to go to the second route directly with manually providing an ID while it doesn't have any dependency on the other component?

Comment: also can this be because of using microsoft-adal-angular6 AuthenticationGuard?

Comment: My thought is that it's either the guard or the resolver which is failing it's checks and by default I think it would then redirect to the empty index route